# Unanswered Questions no longer adhering to favorite tags?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

The question color for favorite tags seems to have disappeared when viewing Unanswered Questions. This morning at work it was showing gold and at some point in the day, they were all white; still are at home.

The URL in question is https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23+vb.net and is where I noticed the problem starting today.

Below, you can see I have [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) as one of my favorite tags (cleared out the rest while testing).

[image]

Curious if anything has changed. Was told that S.O. was untouched by Meta's design update so I am at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yeah, this just changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243554/within-unanswered-tab-with-a-favourite-tag-selected-all-questons-are-highl):

> I would have thought this area should behave just like any of the other tabs:
>
> - Without a favourite tag selected, questions with my favourite tag(s) will be highlighted
> - With a favourite tag selected there won't be any highlighting

m0sa, clearly swayed by the asker's hypnotic use of "u" in the word favorite, implemented this change in behaviour this morning.

Comment: That's... but... erm. =/     I don't like that change. Thanks for finding that. Guess I should start reading Meta SO and Meta SE. Would +6 votes be enough to warrant that change? Was there an actual bug this was fixing? Seems like the bug now is it doesn't put the highlighting back when there are favorites and non-favorite tags.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem here - Unanswered ORs tag combos, while the normal questions list ANDs them by default. Not sure if James & m0sa realized this...

Comment: Heh, sounds like a common mistake that I may or may not still make to this day on stuff.... Do I need to do anything further or is it all in the hands of "top men" now? Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I left a comment under m0sa's answer - he'll likely respond when he wakes up.

Comment: Yeah, missed the OR detail there. But I think the op of the bug has a valid point in the site looking weird with all the unanswered questions highlighted when only favorite tags are selected. So my proposal that IMHO fixes both problems, is to enable favorite tag highlighting on the unanswered page only when there is at least one non-favorite tag selected.

Comment: @m0sa That sounds good to me.

Comment: @TyCobb should be working as described above as of the 2014.11.20.* build revisions

Comment: @m0sa Saw it working yesterday. Thanks again for fixing this.

Comment: Man, why is everyone on the other side of the pond always omitting that `u` in *favourite*?! I find that *so distracting*! :-P

Comment: I think you mean distraucting.

Comment: Not everyone on this side of the pond omits the u in favourite (and a lot of other words). Just those who live or are from outside of "the Great White North".

Comment: Let's call the whole thing off...

Comment: Did this get reverted back? I am noticing the issue again. Think it started last week.

Comment: Should I make another question on this or edit this one?