# Favorite Tag background hilight no longer working?

Tags: discussion, support

I use a custom link to show newest unanswered questions in a specific set of tags, thus:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tagnames=...&tab=newest
```

In the past (until a week or two ago) any questions that contained any of my favorite tags were rendered with a different (kind of peach-colored) background.  Now, most questions get no background, except occasionally, as shown below.  My "favorite tags" setting includes Java, and in the past all the Java questions would be hilighted.  Currently, of the 50 questions on the initial page only one, seen in the screenshot below, is hilighted.

Is this a deliberate change or a bug? If it's deliberate, what is the logic for which questions get hilighted?

[image]

Comment: Favourites have never been highlighted *on their own tag pages* (including combined tag pages). You are not quite using tag pages here, so maybe this is a recent change for unanswered pages.

Comment: So what is the hilighting in the screenshot above?

Comment: @Kendra yes, you are correct, this is a dup.  I didn't find it when searching

Comment: @Kendra the tag query was `xslt+or+xml+or+java+or+or+html+or+linux+or+perl+or+tomcat+or+mysql+or+database+or+xsl+or+xslt-2.0`

Comment: @JimGarrison It took me a little searching to remember, but I knew I had seen a similar question when searching. In this case, your search, I'm assuming, does not contain one of your favorite tags which is on the highlighted question. Edit: Yeah, looking at your query, that's probably what it was.

Comment: I'm still curious why the one question DID get hilighted...

Comment: I figured it out. I'll post an answer with a screenshot to explain.

Comment: Yes it changed recently, check out [those](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243554/within-unanswered-tab-with-a-favourite-tag-selected-all-questons-are-highl) [two](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277219/unanswered-questions-no-longer-adhering-to-favorite-tags) posts for clarification.

Comment: @JimGarrison: presumably because there is a tag on that question that *is* a favourite for you but not part of the tags in the page query. So one of `django`, `django-models` or `django-queryset` in this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's exactly it. I tested it using my own favorites and query.

Comment: So the logic here is that, on the Unanswered tab, favorite-tag hilighting is overridden (turned off) for all tags in the _query_.  To get hilighted, a question must contain a tag that is a member of your favorites but not a member of the query tags.  I guess I can live with that.

Comment: I think this discussion adds enough value that it should probably not be closed as a dup, but if others want to close it go ahead.  I've already VTC and won't rescind my vote.

Comment: @JimGarrison /OT May I ask, which nifty tool you're using, to give the screenshot that nice _ripped off paper sheet_ look?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - A screen capture tool called SnagIt from TechSmith (I have no connection to them, just a user of the tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in your case, this is caused by the fix mentioned in the comments of [this answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277219/unanswered-questions-no-longer-adhering-to-favorite-tags)

Basically, here's how it works:

Your search query used at least one favorite tag for you, in this case it was Java according to you. The highlighted question contains at least one other favorite tag of yours that was *not* in your query.

To illustrate, I did a search for jQuery and regex. jQuery is in my favorite tags.

[image: jQuery search with JavaScript question highlighted.]

As you can see, I also have JavaScript favorited. Questions tagged with both of my favorites are highlighted.

Comment: are you sure you're on the /unanswered/ page?

Comment: @m0sa Well, I was when I entered the search. I didn't realize that searching from the unanswered page would kick you back to the questions page. I updated my answer with an updated image, though the results are the same.

Answer (score 2):

On the `/unanswered/tagged/` page highlighting of your favorite tags that are part of the current query is suppressed when your query contains:

- both a manually added  and  tag and a favorite tag or
- only favorite tags that are combined with  or

both of which would cause a display of a page with *all* of the questions highlighted.